# Change component style when state is set to certain value

Tags: react-native

I have a counter that counts down, when the counter hits zero, I would like a style to change. The counter displays properly but the style never changes. How can I get the style to change when the counter hits a certain value?

Below is the code for a very basic example.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

const ActionScreen = () => {
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(4);
    const [opac, setOpac] = useState(0.8);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => setTimeLeft(timeLeft - 1), 1000);
        if (timeLeft > 2) {
            setOpac(0.8);
            console.log("GT");
        } else {
            setOpac(0.5);
            console.log("LT");
        }
        console.log("opac: ", opac);
        if (timeLeft === 0) {
            // clearInterval(interval);
            setTimeLeft(4);
            // setOpac(0.5);
        }
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, [timeLeft]);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.subActionContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[
                        styles.topButtons,
                        {
                            opacity: opac,
                        }
                    ]}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={styles.buttonText}>
                        {timeLeft}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 25,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    subActionContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignContent: 'space-between',
    },
    topButtons: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: 'center',
        padding: 10,
        color: 'white',
    },
    buttonFail: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginHorizontal: 5,
    }
});

export default ActionScreen;
```

I'm fairly new to React-Native but read somewhere that some styles are set when the app loads and thus don't change but I have also implemented a Dark Mode on my app that sets inline styling, which works well. Why isn't the styling above changing?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is not working? I've just tried your code and the opacity changes just as you have implemented it.

Comment: Have you considered just animating opacity with an animation library? You would get smoother opacity transitions

Comment: @DavidScholz I'm using an Android emulator on a Windows machine. I will try it on an iPhone and Android phone and see if it works. Are you using an emulator or a physical device? Thanks!

Comment: @PhantomSpooks I will take a look at that, my problem is that I'm not getting an opacity change at all, but perhaps it's my emulator that's the issue.

Comment: @DavidScholz If you're still around. I only see the style change if I click the button, without clicking the button, I see no style changes. Any thoughts?

Comment: use Animation to handlle it.

Comment: @John I have created a quick snack, but you are right it does not work on the real device.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your timer and create a method isTimeOut and when it is true you can change the background

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import {useTimerCountDown} from './useCountDownTimer'


export default function App() {

const {minutes, seconds, setSeconds} = useTimerCountDown(0, 10);

const isTimeOut = Boolean(minutes === 0 && seconds === 0);

const handleRestartTimer = () => setSeconds(10);

return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={[styles.welcomeContainer,isTimeOut && 
    styles.timeOutStyle]}>
    <Text>welcome</Text>
  </View>
</View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 paddingTop: 10,
 backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
 padding: 8,
 },
welcomeContainer:{
backgroundColor:'red',
},
timeOutStyle:{
backgroundColor:'blue',
}
});
```

See the useTimerCountDown hook here in this
[working example](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmedhamed70/timerout-changebackground)

Comment: Thank you for the help. If I set the code to change the button's color, it works fine, but if I set it to change the opacity, it doesn't work properly, the opacity only changes if I press the button. I will simply use a different color instead of opacity but I was wondering if you happened to know *why* the opacity doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: you need to use some animation to change the opacity, 
see this tutorial to learn how the animation with opacity works, one of the best tutorials ever

https://codedaily.io/courses/Master-React-Native-Animations/Opacity